# Renew Facebook Access token via cron

Tags: php, facebook, cron

I'm writing a cron script which, periodically posts to facebook.

How would I go about renewing the access token each time the script runs?

Comment: see my answer below, I can give you a more precise one if you tell me exactly what api call you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a User Token, you can only refresh it manually with the user. But you can extend it to an Extended User Token that is valid for 60 days.

If you need a Page Token, just extend it and it will be valid forever (that is, until you change your password).

Information how to generate the different tokens can be found in those articles:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Btw, autoposting to user profiles is not allowed, so i assume an Extended Page Token is what you want.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to post to/as a page. I didn't know that page access tokens didn't have a time limit, so I guess I'll be using that from now.

Comment: careful, there is a difference between page tokens and extended page tokens

Comment: I meant Extended Page tokens. But what I find odd is that extended page tokens lifetime are not documented in any place I've looked so far in the documentation.

Comment: sure, it´s in the link i posted: "To get a longer-lived page access token, exchange the User access token for a long-lived one, as above, and then request the Page token. The resulting page access token will not have any expiry time."